# How to use an Androidx library in a project which is not migrated to Androidx

Tags: android, android-support-library, androidx

My current project is quite stable. Presently I don't want to migrate to Androidx. But I need to use this `com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer:core:10.0.3` library in my project, **which is migrated to Androidx**. So when I'm importing this library it causes gradle build failure.

I found many ways for migrating to Androidx but not the other way.

One solution I can think of downloading the library and replace the Androidx  libraries with support and then import. Apart form this is there any other way ? Like the reverse of jetifier.

Comment: If you want to reverse from androidx to support libraries, then follow this link https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/jetifier#advanced_usage

Comment: I'm looking for a way where I can modify it on the fly in gradle `implementation('com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer:core:10.0.3') {/* here some config */ }`.


Downloading the library and modify it is my last option

Comment: @Sp4Rx Did reverse-jeitifying androidyoutubeplayer:core worked?

Comment: Haven't tried. I moved to AnrdroidX as that was be time consuming for me and every recommended moving to AndroidX @SKP