# Is there any way to use androidX library like(Firebase Crashlytics) in old project without migrating project to androidX?

Tags: android-support-library, androidx, firebase-crash-reporting, android-jetifier

*emphasized text*I need to use firebase Crashlytics in project but not  want to migrate project to android.
I want to know if it possible.

[How to use an Androidx library in a project which is not migrated to Androidx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55493565/how-to-use-an-androidx-library-in-a-project-which-is-not-migrated-to-androidx) :- similar to this

Added dependency for firebase Crashlytics in gradle result in brlow error :
Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:15:5-468:19 to override.

Update 25/05/2021: not find any way, converted entire project to  androidX

Comment: Did you succeed with migrating to Firebase Crashlytics without using `androidx`?

Comment: @Dhiraj did you success any way?, i am looking for same, don't want to migrate whole project to androidx

Comment: Not find any solution migrated entire project.